# Using junction.exe in Windows 2000

Tags: windows, junction, windows-2000

In Linux I am able to do this:

```
ln -s /tmp/somedir/* /tmp/otherdir/
```

Which will create links to all of the files within somedir in otherdir. Is there a way to preform a wildcard operation like this in Windows 2000 using junction.exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`junction` does not accept wildcards and indeed I believe that `ln` does not either. What happens is that the shell expands the wildcards and then passes the resulting list of files/directories to `ln`. You can do the same with junction by using a `for` loop.

That said, you talk about linking to files. Be aware that `junction` does not do that. It can only be used for creating directory symbolic links.

Comment: A lot of useful information here. I know I could do it other ways but I was wanting to keep it clean. I was also not aware that junction only creates directory symbolic links so you just saved me some trouble there.